# error TS2802: Type 'Set<string>' can only be iterated through... with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher, but I already have es2016

Tags: typescript

Here is my code [[LINK](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEWAZwMYQOZoMIA2wApgHbwC+cAZlBCHAOQACREpUAhgdWgPQATdFlwBaDETIxGAbgBQoSLERwA4sRgAlYgWKc0xbWkikDcKrXpNWwdlx78hmHGnGTyfGAE8wxft980WTg5OV14AQAjOABeOFJiAHcUYRdCEnIACgBKADoBThhOSP1iHPk5LFN4TQB5AHUAfQA5AEEAWQBRAGUALjg0GChgUmwAbQBdWLgxuTh5uAAiKB09A0bgAUWAGjmFxc5YdBgdvfnF6mgQQtOFpYBHb1v9y6hrmEaBPwxhsBhbUzPc4EYo6IFLDCFUgQcGLLAAV3IUC8sK8eigsOwZBWaFhgy8ulxuzuixKUCwX1hQ04GAA1kRBos5BMKvovKQMDRERh-uwaMBdAAVCAAGRGfky1AFxH6ADFpdl+gAFOggdDEAA8g2Go0mAD5EGc4CsYPCoKR4kk4Cr6OrMpkcRACAA3YjbY3EABWxB52ViBoQRruVUGHs4Xyg0wSyXlum04eIUHKQYWKwTUFy7AIEHD02o3N5FsyxD9gbu5YWwGocGLuSKUCxMFLKYrwfYobAhwMAjFCTQ01r9cbuRx8II8H0AyGI2weWMRBgmT4AB0oAAfZekDdQTd8bLyVuHj1oJ2uzKdqDd3t+fct8tUHRmMtHisrb085Mv+YUO8UA+ttMI0zBIoDoSM4jfH0YH-V89CAwDWjQQViAAD0XKVdFvO4KFvH9KnbeAMOIABJUgwHhGBOl0EApGmAQIAweEaPIXJGyo4hmJgAAhLxiIETILmlUjyJOW8FGrSUhLIij2M45s7iI4SZOoqRcnDAROldcgxUGMhEwEjAAAtOFGYgdjgNkOS5DlCxrGU4E0qR5NbENCOlfs4kHQ5Gws-sAAlBXaEUlMolTyDyIi0Bg8sqxrSLnJfVz+V0PN3LGAAGFk7zuIYvENL9yySzZYxgRNiAEAdOESThgDcoVRXFNBJMwiKBVKpNMmdP0YgNZ04AAQhiOJFkWLCCoWJLuAITQIESDyLOq2rrVVdU1IIAhMmKtqyoEXJrjASUNCM7RdFKbIxvGuB6MSUhs3DTIppmuaLqPKhIRgIy7NA6AEvGkMnWIXJEzAgTOm+yMwDoDA-DQGdkplczgZ+6LDx-VGjRw+Q8Mszl8xsgEaCOwyTrWMoVlOgw+P6bUZ0VZbbQMDUTK8SY4DXFQkaganp1GcwAyNXL8pcgiVAKIpzGmKqaoiSJWI0EnSgdVZSj4l67hNM0LUhhiYYVgxkEKTglYpkiBHdMXOBet7Ck+4twd+9WNE1oWX05-oAAM9eIOBElqwy4GI5A4AAEgQcnSb4qh6L8eIIHgVDjnd39op-PC8Z5AntehtA0C9g2imNiOBG5nVsHNw3+nULRlYMIwTAMZsjSSpAESRPK4kYABVUhaWhG7GHdLEOBjuJJndfFCWmMe4DRQ5pi7nu+9IRgJbiC3osmo5Bnmi21K3mA0AAfj2zgwGPh79-9Cz99yUhOBol6krJClvbXw3ck2KQqxIS9cgw9rNoVR6nATYdYfCvyGkwLihwX6MDyPtTIz8IBfCvkgr4uRnTcHhCWDeIt3rQjou-EEkRHwnwOvgiAV8KG5AoS9cIcBETAHuNgvAUJKGj1yJw6McBugaEyLQrKbZqhXW+L8QsO936vHeGgMhmQviYDEQCDyBp5E-GAH8JR+RRHqPEY-EWUjCiEKKH-K4hQZEIIMfAYBljb73xwU3EWxDHxGM4LkJxBBzGn0yO4q+7jbEP2ivQxhzDiAilBB4qenDb5Wl4YudxaBsiCImiLR47crqSNMQfWRlir42NSXo4R1I6QMisek4xRT6THFkRUq+FS6y1UwtFPgfA4BJS+EQNU7U6IMSYqpNiYVuK8X4owdpoBaqJjgRgrB3s1zs0YGuWQDjhGjM6YmeeCzcHCMsaVAQ0DyTINfnANBgNPQQBGHInQYz2oFNDNs8qrCYDNHYQw0gTCWFsNyKc85KzxlQBuYRTJOz1DD3mkPHEnyzmkAuR035-yaCAvKmEkhES4jBOwUi0hXyoU-OuZs25CKBDdG8JPOIE8-AQu+Zc1Zfy8UAreIUHZgouDFOONMCpJSKXYqpbC2lcBIbEDuQIZA2iNHtjoiK8RdYIBEtLjkEcxAwAgmhpkRgiwB5MBGpMlYiqaRlD4NsPgZcmDujgbywVwqFE6KUfPNVcAADUfKVjmoldah1qrFl3HoeaiuFlSAsymKPO84cVZmzvIcf429iStksVGisqTY3lmdZa0VpgE0KQJRijxaaFiCoeU87N8xW65QLTPdEJbBXApxOWglRKCR+GrfSmAOy9kvwbe8RlzLKmDCNFlI0GtzTwsbTs-OnAsahHTrZa6t0cz8Qtv0ZmkxfpJQwGgZ0eB2ClXINMRYc7SpoT4Cu50MgjJdg0DECi1BRAAA5tiLHtXAOoTQ2hdG6JygSt6-QOsWJuO9Drd4INfgaE5kL32jTyFigSP64VkBfgITuwxpgwYOZ3TQxF+GrvXeQJyvKiA926YxTiNC0ylVklIASnBRqBJGLSXIBgYCtCbcMSIFEyiLEMk6xGHIDlweGHQ6jtGNAMenMx0qAkp13S2O6RYIAvCfHfoeyjRp6IEdUpEZBXg1JgF8KQAQeBDICn4rh2k+44DNIfcQZhwAVgVVeHAeUTqIAoSNEZmhRA6TJgoEAA)]

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",     
    "module": "commonjs", 
    "esModuleInterop": true,   
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
    "strict": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true     
  }
}
```

https://github.com/steve-davey/discogsCSV

Here is the start of the transpiled .JS file:

```
"use strict";
var __awaiter = (this && this.__awaiter) || function (thisArg, _arguments, P, generator) {
    function adopt(value) { return value instanceof P ? value : new P(function (resolve) { resolve(value); }); }
    return new (P || (P = Promise))(function (resolve, reject) {
        function fulfilled(value) { try { step(generator.next(value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function rejected(value) { try { step(generator["throw"](value)); } catch (e) { reject(e); } }
        function step(result) { result.done ? resolve(result.value) : adopt(result.value).then(fulfilled, rejected); }
        step((generator = generator.apply(thisArg, _arguments || [])).next());
    });
};
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
```

But I am getting

```
csv.ts:73:27 - error TS2802: Type 'Set<string>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher.                                             
73     let uniqueCatno = [...new Set(catno)];
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
csv.ts:77:28 - error TS2802: Type 'Set<string>' can only be iterated through when using the '--downlevelIteration' flag or with a '--target' of 'es2015' or higher.
77     let uniqueLabels = [...new Set(labels)];
```

I don't get that, because I have

```
"target": "es2016"
```

Any help please?

Comment: I don't see any errors in playground. Do you have multiple tsconfig in your project ?

Comment: Playground links are a great **adjunct**, but always include the code *in the question*, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future.

Comment: From the fact you're getting the error, TypeScript is configured to target something before ES2015. It sounds like you have multiple conflicting configurations, so the one you've looked at that has `"target": "es2016"` isn't the one being used. You'll need to look around for the conflicting configuration.

Comment: I don't have multiple tsconfig's in my project, at least not that I am aware of. I will try to update the OP with the full code; sorry for not including it.

Comment: I'm trying to add the full code, but getting "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details" 

Comment: How are you building? It doesn't look like tsc is using your tsconfig if it's ignoring the target, but I'm not sure how we can help you further without a [mre] of the problem.

Comment: I'm building it using VSCode, by doing `tsc csv.ts` in the terminal. The problem with the Minimal, Reproducible Example is that this site literally won't let me add all my code to the OP. It keeps coming up "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details". I tried adding some random filler text but that didn't help.